# Connection to https://api.parse.com refused using 1.5.1 of Android Parse SDK

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

My app uses 1.5.1 of the Android Parse SDK.

Many of my customers connect to Parse.com without issue.  I have some customers who are receiving an error as follows:

```
i/o failure: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://api.parse.com refused

com.parse.ParseException: i/o failure: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://api.parse.com refused
    at com.parse.ParseRequest.connectionFailed(SourceFile:387)
    at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.call(SourceFile:271)
    at com.parse.Task$3.run(SourceFile:199)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I am running the code in a thread and have a timer that will stop the timer and put a message that it is unable to connect.  It is failing before this timer times out.

Here it the code that is failing:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       try {
           Parse.initialize(mContext, mAppId, mAppKey);
           ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1 = ParseQuery.getQuery("myTable");
           query1.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.NETWORK_ONLY);
           ParseObject metaData = query1.getFirst();
           // do other work...
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
           Log.e(TAG, e);
       }
   }
});
```

The customers show screen shots with active data connections (both cellular and wireless).

Any ideas on why some customers are failing and most work?

Comment: Maybe because the api.parse.com server refused the connection?

Comment: Granted, but why does it refuse for some and not others?  I'm hoping someone with experience with parse will be able to shed light on why certain devices are refused access.  It's not a throttling issue or they would connect sometimes and not others.  But there are specific devices that are not able to connect.  Period.  And this is with the most recent version (1.5.1) of the Parse Android SDK.  I updated the ticket to reflect that this is an Android SDK question.

Comment: This has been resolved.  Parse reported they were having intermittent outages with their servers.  I checked their status before reporting this issue and didn't see that, so looks like I missed it.  Thanks.