# Parse Exception: Connection to https://api.parse.com refused

Tags: android, http, https, parse-platform

I have an application that is working on 2 out of 3 phones. On the third phone, Note 3, I am receiving the following error:

```
com.parse.ParseException: i/o failure: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://api.parse.com refused
```

All 3 phones are rooted and are connected to the same wifi network. I have also attempted to use a data connection.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: May be same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469182/connection-to-https-api-parse-com-refused-using-1-5-1-of-android-parse-sdk

Comment: @DevrimTuncer OP stated that he has tried of 3 phones, 2 of which worked. So it's not an issue with Parse being down as your link suggests.

Comment: A possible root cause might be AdBlock or Cyanogenmod blocking access to api.parse.com, is anything like that true for the devices it is not working on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I had the same problem for some time and guess what? Bjorn was right. I just reverted the Hosts file in adfree and problem solved